# Read H264 streaming from Elp H264 with OpenCV + Python

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, h.264

I'm trying to read an udp streaming of a H264 encoded image. The software structure is like follows:

On a BeagleBoneBlack (Ubuntu 16.04) I've an Elp H264 cam (see here: [https://www.amazon.com/ELP-Support-Android-Windows-Surveillance/dp/B00VDSBH9G](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00VDSBH9G) ). I stream frames with ffmpeg on a Unicast UDP Stream.

I want to read this images from python and opencv to be able to process them.

I tried with this simple code to see if the cap is opened or not:

```
import cv2
```

> ```
> try:
>      cap = cv2.VideoCapture("udp://localhost:1234/")
>     cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC, CV_FOURCC('H', '2', '6', '4'));
> except Exception, e:
>     print str(e)
> ```

But when I run this script python says:

> DtsGetHWFeatures: Create File Failed DtsGetHWFeatures: Create File
>   Failed Running DIL (3.22.0) Version DtsDeviceOpen: Opening HW in mode
>   0 DtsDeviceOpen: Create File Failed libva info: VA-API version 0.38.1
>   libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1 libva error:
>   va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)
>   libva info: VA-API version 0.38.1 libva info: va_getDriverName()
>   returns -1 libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva
>   error,driver_name=(null) libva info: VA-API version 0.38.1 libva info:
>   va_getDriverName() returns -1 libva error: va_getDriverName() failed
>   with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null) libva info: VA-API version
>   0.38.1 libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1 libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)
>   GStreamer Plugin: Embedded video playback halted; module vaapidecode
>   reported: Could not initialize supporting             library. OpenCV
>   Error: Unspecified error (GStreamer: unable to start pipeline ) in
>   cvCaptureFromCAM_GStreamer, file /builddir/build/BUILD/opencv-
>   2.4.12.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp, line 816 /builddir/build/BUILD/opencv-2.4.12.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:816:
>   error: (-2) GStreamer: unable     to start pipeline  in function
>   cvCaptureFromCAM_GStreamer

Can anybody help me?

Thanks,

Francesco.

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

I solved this problem updating ffmpeg.